# Email SPAM and mismatched URLs: are query strings allowed?

Tags: email

Many email clients will flag your email as SPAM if the anchor text in your links are pretending to be a link to a different place. For example:

`<a href="https://some-dodgy-phishing-url.com">https://yourbank.com/verify_account</a>`

But do they do the same thing for query strings? For example:

`<a href="https://yourbank.com/verify_account?email=john@gmail.com">https://yourbank.com/verify_account</a>`

The link is not pretending to be something else, but it does include some query strings which are not exactly the same as the anchor text.